# a smart brute force algorithm for finding a book?

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

i want to write a brute force algorithm to try and find a book in a library. How long will it take you to work out if the book you are looking for is not there?
any smart brute force method?

**i am thinking to search the name of the book in the list where library book names are located and start from the center of the list?**

Comment: Unless you order your data, you'll have no "smart brute force". If you order your data (complexity NlogN), you can find what you want in logN time, using a binary search

Comment: Brute force, almost by definition, tends not to be "smart"

Comment: If you're looking for a quick way to say "this book is not here", look up Bloom Filters.

Comment: To reduce the cost of finding the book, compare only the first character of the target name with the name of the book. Only if the first character matches should the entire name of the book be checked.

Comment: 1. filter all books so you can narrow it down (you're the only one who knows what to look for), 2. add all those entries to a database, 3. datamine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this Article on [why GNU grep is fast](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) and try his methods. In short he says:

> - Use Boyer-Moore (and unroll its inner loop a few times).
> - Roll your own unbuffered input using raw system calls.  Avoid copying
>     the input bytes before searching them.  (Do, however, use buffered
>     *output*.  The normal grep scenario is that the amount of output is
>     small compared to the amount of input, so the overhead of output
>     buffer copying is small, while savings due to avoiding many small
>     unbuffered writes can be large.)
> - Don't look for newlines in the input until after you've found a match.
> - Try to set things up (page-aligned buffers, page-sized read chunks,
>     optionally use mmap) so the kernel can ALSO avoid copying the bytes.
>
> The key to making programs fast is to make them do practically nothing. ;-)

Grep does exactly what you want: brute force a search in unordered data – and his algorithm is smart, even though it's brute force.